# pip installation via easy_install not working on osx

Tags: python, installation, pip, easy-install

So I tried installing pip..

Check here for my terminal session:
http://showterm.io/02378a6eae5b922121cbc

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to add:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
```

to my path.

Answer (score 0):

add /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin